# How to avoid having to reference an external XML file?

Tags: c, glade

I am writing an app in C and using Glade3 to make the GUI (and GTK builder).

Glade 3 doesn't allow C code generation anymore (which I understand the reasons for), but now all applications need to have the XML file hanging around the compiled app like an annoying .dll file. Does anyone have any knowledge of project to create C code for it, or how to embed the XML file in the code itself? I imagine this could be done, but it would be a pain I bet.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

`gtk_builder_new_from_string(const gchar *string, gssize length);`

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-new-from-string

Just stringify the glade3 xml file (in GtkBuilder format) and include it as a string.

It is still *possible* to use glade-2.12 to generate gtk2 code and then port it to gtk3; however if you are going to do that it may be worth it to simply modify that version of glade to output the gtk3 syntax directly.